# NoMethodError Comments Controller - Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, nomethoderror

I have two models comments and programmes. And i get this error.

[image]

My **comments_conroller.rb** looks like this

```
def create
    @programmme = Programme.find(params[:programme_id])

    @comment = @programme.comments.create!(params[:comment])

        if @comment.save
            redirect_to @comment.programme, notice: "Comment has been sent."
        else
            format.html { redirect_to @comment.programme, notice: "There was an error creating your comment."}
        end

  end
```

I have also tried using build instead of create.

```
 def create
    @programmme = Programme.find(params[:programme_id])

    @comment = @programme.comments.build(params[:comment])

        if @comment.save
            redirect_to @comment.programme, notice: "Comment has been sent."
        else
            format.html { redirect_to @comment.programme, notice: "There was an error creating your comment."}
        end

  end
```

**programme.rb**

```
class Programme < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :biography, :broadcastTime, :description, :title

  # Associations
    has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy

end
```

**comment.rb**

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :location, :message, :name, :requestFor, :song

  #Associations
  belongs_to :programme

end
```

And my **routes.rb** looks like this

```
DigneRadio::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :programmes do
      resources :comments
  end

  resources :replays
  resources :articles

end
```

Not sure where i'm going wrong but i would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mistake in your spelling of programme, first you use @programmme(with 3m) and in next step you use @programme.

Comment: @Vezu You still have to be careful with the spellings, you misspelled my name now :P